# Get realtime alerts on site's page loading time

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, network-traffic

is it possible to get realtime alerts when a page takes more than x seconds to load? (send an email)
I have a custom alerts on Google Analytics, but it send me an email the day after. I want it in real time because I'm tracking an issue about site performance.

Any workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the following Google Analytics custom alert:

```
all traffic -> Avg. Page Load Time -> % increases by more than -> 10% -> previous day
```